# How can the code being allowed to continue from one question to another question even though the input answer had wrong for 3 attempts?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
import time
import random
#declare variables and constant
guessingelement = ["Hydrogen", "Magnesium", "Cobalt", "Mercury", "Aluminium", "Uranium", "Antimony"]
nicephrases = ["Nice job", "Marvellous", "Wonderful", "Bingo", "Dynamite"]
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False
guess_no = 0
score = 0

#set the maximum number of questions for looping and random pick an element from the list before deleting it
for i in range(7):
    randomelement = random.choice(guessingelement)
    guessingelement.remove(randomelement)
    time.sleep(2)

#tips of the element
if randomelement == "Hydrogen" and not out_of_guesses:
    print("Tip 1: It is the most flammable of all the known substances.")
    print("Tip 2: It reacts with oxides and chlorides of many metals, like copper, lead, mercury, to produce free metals.")
    print("Tip 3: It reacts with oxygen to form water.")

    #test the number of tries so that it doesn't exceed 3 times if answer is wrong
    while guess != randomelement and not(out_of_guesses):
        if guess_count < guess_limit:
            guess = input("Enter guess: ")
            guess_count += 1
        else:
            out_of_guesses = True

    #add score, praise when answer is correct and encourage when answer is wrong for 3 times
    if out_of_guesses:
        print("Out of Guesses, NICE EFFORT!")
    else:
        print(random.choice(nicephrases), ", YOU GET IT!")
        score = score + 1
```

```
#tips of the element
    if randomelement == "Magnesium" and not out_of_guesses:
        print("Tip 1: It has the atomic number of 12.")
        print("Tip 2: It's oxide can be extracted into free metal through electrolysis.")
        print("Tip 3: It is a type of metal.")
```

Same as first questions' code..
and so on....

```
In the progress of changing:`
#tips of the element
    if randomelement == "Hydrogen":
        print("Tip 1: It is the most flammable of all the known substances.")
        print("Tip 2: It reacts with oxides and chlorides of many metals, like copper, lead, mercury, to produce free metals.")
        print("Tip 3: It reacts with oxygen to form water.")

    #test the number of tries so that it doesn't exceed 3 times if answer is wrong
```

```
        while guess != randomelement:
            if guess_count < guess_limit:
                guess = input("Enter guess: ")
                guess_count += 1
            else:
                print(random.choice(wronganswers))

        #add score, praise when answer is correct and encourage when answer is wrong for 3 times
        else:
            print(random.choice(nicephrases), ", YOU GET IT!")
            score = score + 1
```

However, after 3 times of attempts, it keeps printing the elements from the wronganswers list non-stop,
and can't proceed to the next question.
The output I expected is that it will show an element from the list when the input answer is wrong and
proceed to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I wrote this code for myself in a new way. I have used recursion to keep the guess happening and simple used a while loop that will break when max attempts go beyond 3.

```
import random

elements = ["hydrogen", "magnesium", "cobalt", "mercury", "aluminium", "uranium", "antimony"]
nice_phrases = ["Nice job", "Marvellous", "Wonderful", "Bingo", "Dynamite"]

# I went ahead and created a dictionary of lists for storing the Hints
hints = {
    'hydrogen':
        [
            "Tip 1: It is the most flammable of all the known substances.",
            "Tip 2: It reacts with oxides and chlorides of many metals, "
            "like copper, lead, mercury, to produce free metals.",
            "Tip 3: It reacts with oxygen to form water."
        ],
    'magnesium':
        [
            "Tip 1: It has the atomic number of 12.",
            "Tip 2: It's oxide can be extracted into free metal through electrolysis.",
            "Tip 3: It is a type of metal."
        ],
}

score = 0


def guess_again():
    global score
    random_element = random.choice(elements)
    max_attempts = 3

    # this will remove the element from occurring again
    for x in elements:
        if x == random_element:
            elements.remove(x)

    while max_attempts > 0:
        user_guess = input("Take a Guess").lower()

        if user_guess == random_element:
            print(f"{random.choice(nice_phrases)}, you got it!")
            score += 1
            # If the answer is right calling the function again will continue the game
            guess_again()
        else:
            max_attempts -= 1
            print("That was a wrong guess. Here is a Hint")
            if random_element in hints:
                print(hints[random_element])
            else:
                print("Sorry no hints available at the moment")
        if max_attempts == 0:
            print("Sorry your out of guesses")
            print(f"{random.choice} was the element")


guess_again()
```

If the Answer is right it will select the next element and the game continues until all the elements in the list are finished. I have coded it to give 3 attempts for each elements. If you want the maximum 3 attempts for the entire duration of the game just declare max_attempts outside the function and give it global scope like done for score